# Changing Ubuntu Touch default browser search engine

Tags: ubuntu-touch, search

I want to change my Ubuntu Touch default browser search engine to duckduckgo. However, when I go into browser > settings > search (engine), duckduckgo is not listed in the available options. I cannot see how I can add it. Am I missing something or how can I change the search engine to one of my own selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phil UK, I'm running 15.04(OTA-13) on my Nexus 4, and DuckDuckGo is listed in the browser Settings for Search engine. What's your environment?

Comment: Same on my BQ Aquaris 4.5 - DuckDuckGo is listed.

Comment: I can see it now in the options

Answer (score 1):

Should be available. Don't know, why not. You can add searchengines by adding xml files into /usr/share/webbrowser-app/webbrowser/searchengines (rootfs must be readwrite). Take an existing one as example and test the right properties because I don't, how exactly you must configure them. It depends on the searchengine.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I will check it out later tonight when I have the tablet to hand. There must be an easier way though surly to change the browser default search engine.